# Beamer (with Bergen theme) how to move ToC from sidebar to "main part" of slide?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

How would I move the table of contents produced by `\tableofcontents` from the left sidebar to the main part of the slide? It produces a lot of unused white space, as in the following:

[image]

This code shows a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Bergen}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Summary}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}

  \section{A brief introduction to AAA AAA}

  \begin{frame}{Introduction to AAA AAA}
    Whatever
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Introduction to AAA AAA}
    Whatever
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Introduction to AAA AAA}
    Whatever
  \end{frame}

  \section{An even shorter introduction to BBB BBB}

  \begin{frame}{Introduction to BBB BBB}
    Whatever
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Introduction to BBB BBB}
    Whatever
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to move the tableofcontents into the main text area you need to re-set the following three templates:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsection}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\inserttocsubsection}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{\inserttocsubsubsection}
```

[image]

However, since the Bergen theme is designed specifically to put things inside the sidebar I'm not sure this will look good, you'll need to check with a full-blown toc.

Specifically, the Bergen theme calls the `inmargin` inner theme, which is responsible for the toc placement. In the relevant .sty file you'll find:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc}
\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc}
...
```

and the other relevant definitions.